# IE compatible Javascript not working in Chrome. Inconsistencies with children?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When I run this, I get "oldSelected2" is undefined.  This seems to work in IE, but not Chrome.  The problem seems to be with the `oldSelected.children[findSelected(selectReplace)]`.  I leave the drop down menu where `selectReplace = 0`, so a 0 goes into the `oldSelected.children[]`, however when this runs, it returns undefined.  It returns undefined for any number put into it.  However, in IE, instead of undefined, it returns the object, and everything works fine.  Is there anything in my findSelected function at the bottom that can cause this to break?

```
var selectReplace = document.getElementById(colName + index)
oldSelected = selectReplace.children[1];
oldSelected2 = oldSelected.children[findSelected(selectReplace)]

oldSelected2.removeAttribute("selected");
el = oldSelected.children[baseSiteIx.selectedIndex + 1];
el.setAttribute("selected", 1);
selectReplace.selectedIndex = findSelected(baseSiteIx) + 1;
```

Heres the xsl

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var siteArray = new Array();
    siteArray[0] = new Option("007", "3135", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;","selected");siteArray[1] = new Option("081730", "3287", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[2] = new Option("11", "3226", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[3] = new Option("12", "3327", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[4] = new Option("13", "73", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[5] = new Option("13&", "3194", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[6] = new Option("14", "1113", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[7] = new Option("140", "3347", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[8] = new Option("15", "3387", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[9] = new Option("16", "3407", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[10] = new Option("2001", "3487", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[11] = new Option("2002", "3488", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[12] = new Option("32", "3225", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[13] = new Option("400", "3224", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[14] = new Option("402", "3221", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[15] = new Option("403", "3280", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[16] = new Option("41", "3328", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[17] = new Option("604", "3527", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[18] = new Option("605", "3202", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[19] = new Option("680", "3201", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[20] = new Option("69", "3200", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[21] = new Option("786104", "3253", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[22] = new Option("87", "3254", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[23] = new Option("A1A", "1153", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[24] = new Option("ARG", "3103", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[25] = new Option("AVK", "3281", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[26] = new Option("AVNET", "3307", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[27] = new Option("B1", "2533", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[28] = new Option("BBY", "3447", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[29] = new Option("D1", "2813", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[30] = new Option("DAL", "3472", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[31] = new Option("ECONTROLS", "3247", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[32] = new Option("ECT", "3248", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[33] = new Option("FL01", "3250", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[34] = new Option("FL04", "3249", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[35] = new Option("FWB", "3203", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[36] = new Option("LEX", "3471", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[37] = new Option("MAIN", "3134", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[38] = new Option("MANKATO", "3219", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[39] = new Option("MIL", "3474", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[40] = new Option("MIS", "3468", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[41] = new Option("PITT", "3256", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[42] = new Option("RECEIPT", "3229", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[43] = new Option("ST5678", "3260", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[44] = new Option("STP", "3473", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[45] = new Option("STPETER", "3218", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[46] = new Option("TENN", "3257", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[47] = new Option("TOR", "3470", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[48] = new Option("VAN", "3467", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[49] = new Option("VMI", "3252", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");siteArray[50] = new Option("WNJ", "3282", "font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;");writeSelectBox(siteArray, "SiteIxFill", 1, "", "z-index:100; width: 110;");</script>

<select size="1" id="SiteIxFill" name="SiteIxFill" onchange="" style="z-index:100; width: 110;">
<option value="3468" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;">MIS</option>
<option value="3256" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;">PITT</option>
<option value="3229" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;">RECEIPT</option>
<option value="3260" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;">ST5678</option>
<option value="3473" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;">STP</option>
<option value="3218" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;">STPETER</option>
<option value="3257" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;">TENN</option>
<option value="3470" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;">TOR</option>
<option value="3467" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;">VAN</option>
<option value="3252" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;">VMI</option>
<option value="3282" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;">WNJ</option>
</select>

<input id="SiteIxFillStart" name="SiteIxFillStart" value="1" size="2">
<input id="SiteIxFillEnd" name="SiteIxFillEnd" value="1" size="2">
<input type="button" value="  Fill  " size="5" onclick="fillSelectBoxes('SiteIx');">
```

Here is the find selected

```
function findSelected(el) {
var selected = null;


ec = el.children[1].children;   //the table is the first child
var ecl = ec.length;

for (var i=0; i<ecl; i++) {
    if (ec[i].getAttribute("selected") != null) {
        if (selected == null) { // Found first selected
            selected = i;
        }
        else
            ec[i].removeAttribute("selected");  //Like I said. Only one selected!
    }
}
if (selected == null)
    selected = 0;   //When starting this is the most logic start value if none is present

return selected;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code into a smaller, more readable format. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: What does `siteArray[]` have to do with the problem? What element is being found with `document.getElementById(colName + index)` -- where does `index` come from?

Comment: @Barmar The colName and index are the rows in my table.  Those are working correctly.  This code is designed to auto fill each row with a value in a select box.  The only problem I am having is in line 3 of the first block of code returning undefined.

Comment: Also, el = oldSelected.children[baseSiteIx.selectedIndex + 1]; is returning undefined.  I'm trying to figure out why atm.

Comment: What table are you talking about? It's not clear how the Javascript you posted is related to the HTML you've posted, so it's hard to tell what might be going wrong.